# MVC 4 - View inside a form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC. I have this view model:

```
public class ABCView
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<orders> Order { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I want a view where the top of the form will contain Name and Message. In the bottom, I need only TWO orders side-by-side. How can I achieve this for Create/Edit operations. Any links will be helpful, thanks.

Comment: I would have the Order parameter twice, then have a dropdown box for each one. `Html.DropdownBoxFor()`

Answer (score 0):

I would simply pass this model to a view, then output using @Html.TextBoxFor Name and Message where you want them. On the bottom of the form have a foreach loop which goes through the List and outputs the orders.

Great, simple example: 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view